# The method 'where' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: where(Closure: (UserModel) => bool)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having this error and i dont know how to resolved it pls help me out:

```
    The method 'where' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: where(Closure: (UserModel) => bool)
```

This is where the error is coming from:

The List is of type the UserModel class which is writen below

```
List<UserModel> userList;

final List<UserModel> suggestionList = query.isEmpty
    ?[]
    : userList.where((UserModel user) {
      String _getUsername = user.username.toLowerCase();
      String _query = query.toLowerCase();
      String _getName = user.name.toLowerCase();
      bool matchesUsername = _getUsername.contains(_query);
      bool matchesName = _getName.contains(_query);

      return (matchesUsername || matchesName);
}).toList();
```

This is the class which the `userList` is calling from:
This is the Model class that is begin called.

```
    class UserModel {
  String uid;
  String name;
  String email;
  String username;
  String status;
  int state;
  String profilePhoto;

  UserModel({
    this.uid,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.username,
    this.status,
    this.state,
    this.profilePhoto,
  });

  Map toMap(UserModel user) {
    var data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['uid'] = user.uid;
    data['name'] = user.name;
    data['email'] = user.email;
    data['username'] = user.username;
    data["status"] = user.status;
    data["state"] = user.state;
    data["profile_photo"] = user.profilePhoto;
    return data;
  }

  UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> mapData) {
    this.uid = mapData['uid'];
    this.name = mapData['name'];
    this.email = mapData['email'];
    this.username = mapData['username'];
    this.status = mapData['status'];
    this.state = mapData['state'];
    this.profilePhoto = mapData['profile_photo'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Show the code where `userList` is defined and populated.

Comment: @GrahamD `List<UserModel> userList;`

Comment: here is the class `class UserModel {
  String uid;
  String name;
  String email;
  String username;
  String status;
  int state;
  String profilePhoto;

  UserModel({
    this.uid,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.username,
    this.status,
    this.state,
    this.profilePhoto,
  });
`

Comment: here is the rest `Map toMap(UserModel user) {
    var data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['uid'] = user.uid;
    data['name'] = user.name;
    data['email'] = user.email;
    data['username'] = user.username;
    data["status"] = user.status;
    data["state"] = user.state;
    data["profile_photo"] = user.profilePhoto;
    return data;
  }`

Comment: `UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> mapData) {
    this.uid = mapData['uid'];
    this.name = mapData['name'];
    this.email = mapData['email'];
    this.username = mapData['username'];
    this.status = mapData['status'];
    this.state = mapData['state'];
    this.profilePhoto = mapData['profile_photo'];
  }`

Comment: i hope this is ok?

Comment: Please add that code as an update at the bottom of your original questions

Comment: @GrahamD ok i have done so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "userList" variable is not initialized. The easiest fix you can do is to initialize it with an empty list when you declare it.

```
List<UserModel> userList = <UserModel>[];
```